# Set password of user created with Scripted API in Service now

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I am new to the Service now and trying to build a Client Web-app with Service Now.
My requirement is to register a user in Service Now using my web app.

I have tried to do so with Table API and Scripted Rest API.
Though I am able to create the user (makes an entry in sys_user table) but the created user is not able to login on Service Now portal.

If I login as admin and change the password of created user the user is able to login.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Below is my Scripted API -

```js
(function process( /*RESTAPIRequest*/ request, /*RESTAPIResponse*/ response) {

  // implement resource here
  var requestBody = request.body.data;
  var gr = new GlideRecord('sys_user');
  gr.initialize();
  gr.user_name = requestBody.user_name;
  gr.first_name = requestBody.first_name;
  gr.last_name = requestBody.last_name;
  gr.title = requestBody.title;
  gr.department = requestBody.department;
  gr.user_password = requestBody.user_password;
  gr.active = requestBody.active;
  gr.email = requestBody.email;
  gr.mobile_phone = requestBody.mobile_phone;
  gr.insert();
  //Create a body object.  Add property value pairs to the body.
  var body = {};
  body.user_name = gr.user_name;
  body.sys_id = gr.sys_id;
  body.password = gr.user_password;
  response.setBody(body);
})(request, response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a hook for this question.
When you create the user instead of setting the password before gr.insert(), try updating the record for setting the password as per the following code.

```
gr.user_password.setDisplayValue(requestBody.user_password);
gr.update();
```

Looks like password in sys_user table is a one way encrypted field. So you need to set the display value.